# Invoke function with $(window).resize and on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to invoke my function when the page is initially loaded and when the window is resized however I am unsure how this can be done. I currently have the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var offerPageMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 969px)');
  if(mq.matches) {
      $('.mobileposition').append($('.offer-key-info'));
  } else {
      $('.offer-content').append($('.offer-key-info'));
  }
});
```

As you can see when the page is resized this function will run however I also want it to run on the initial load of the page also.

Any idea how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `resize()` with no parameter to raise the event too:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var offerPageMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 969px)');
    $(mq.matches ? '.mobileposition' : '.offer-content').append($('.offer-key-info'));
}).resize(); // call here
```

Alternatively you could extract the logic to a function and call it under both events:

```
function foo() {
    var offerPageMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 969px)');
    $(mq.matches ? '.mobileposition' : '.offer-content').append($('.offer-key-info'));
}

$(window).resize(foo);
foo();
```

I would also suggest that it may be better to instead do this using CSS media queries instead of relying on JS. You could have a copy of the `.offer-key-info` element in the DOM in both places and the hide/show the required one depending on the media query which matches the required resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
var offerPageMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 969px)');
  if(mq.matches) {
      $('.mobileposition').append($('.offer-key-info'));
  } else {
      $('.offer-content').append($('.offer-key-info'));
  }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
   myFunction();
});

$(window).load(function(){
   myFunction();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   myFunction();
});
```